# My Time Capsule insists on being the DHCP server, but I already have one

Tags: time-capsule, router

I have today joined the 21st century and started using FTTC, leaving aDSL behind as a fond memory. The modem that my telco provides presents a cat5 socket that my PPPoE capable router plugs into.

My router (currently) is an Apple Time Capsule. Not an obvious choice as a router/firewall, but I had it already and it *does* handle PPPoE at the cost of one cat5 socket.

The downside is that it insists on choosing it's own IP address (from one of 3) and being the DHCP server. I happen to have my own DHCP server and DNS server with a small DNS zone that I'd like to keep using, but the Time Capsule doesn't give me a means to achieving this that I can see.

Can anyone advise how I can configure the TC to use a static LAN-side IP address, and *not* to be the DHCP server, while at the same employing NAT to share the single IP address I get amongst my machines on my LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time Capsule can only handle PPPoE if it is also acting as the DHCP Server. You will need to get a different device, or allow the Time Capsule to be the actual DHCP Server, turning off that function on your provided modem: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH5104